# Oracle Error with Group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently trying to use a case statement before a group by command. Getting the below error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 188 Column: 12

```
select "CUSIP", "SIDE", TRADEDATE, ACCOUNTNO, SUM("QUANTITY") as CompressedQuantity,

(case when quantity = 0 THEN 0 ELSE trunc(sum("PRICE"*"QUANTITY")/sum("QUANTITY"),6) END) as AVERAGEPRICE
from rawtable
group by "SIDE", "TRADEDATE", "ACCOUNTNO", "CUSIP")

select CompressedQuantity,"SIDE", "TRADEDATE", "ACCOUNTNO", "CUSIP" FROM compresstable
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the aggregate  sum(quantity), not quantity

```
select "CUSIP", "SIDE", TRADEDATE, ACCOUNTNO, SUM("QUANTITY") as CompressedQuantity,
    case when sum(quantity) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE trunc(sum("PRICE"*"QUANTITY")/sum("QUANTITY"),6) END as AVERAGEPRICE
from rawtable
group by "SIDE", "TRADEDATE", "ACCOUNTNO", "CUSIP"
```

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You must add Quantity to your group by.

```
group by "SIDE", "TRADEDATE", "ACCOUNTNO", "CUSIP", SUM("QUANTITY")
```